# After change the system language it updated in local app language how to avoid?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to avoid after change the system language its updated in local app language in android kotlin

How to avoid after change the system language its overriding  local application language in android kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore system language changes as below - >

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en"
    }
}
```

if you want to disable Rtl ->

```
 <application
      android:supportsRtl="false" // <== add this line here
```